# Question deleted

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [How to deal with a colleague that systematically removes people from email recipients?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115582/how-to-deal-with-a-colleague-that-systematically-removes-people-from-email-recip)

I don't understand why my question has been deleted. I think I don't violate any rule. I don't receive any message or warning. Can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 15):

Okay, let's cut to the chase: your account has been identified as one of a number being created by the same person with the sole purpose of posting fake questions. Regardless of your reasons in wasting our time and yours, we are proceeding to delete those posts since they are not made in good faith and are thus not welcome on this site.

We have a number of ways to determine malicious actors which we won't disclose here for obvious reasons but if you believe this judgement was made in error, please [consult the advice given here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges).

Feel free to ask real, pertinent questions about problems you are facing, but please refrain from making up stories. If you are serious about participating in this network, we'd also encourage you to stick with a single account to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 13):

While in isolation, this hypothetical-sounding question is ok, there's a wider consideration.

In the [Tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) page (which you've read several times, it seems), it states:

> Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

(my bold)

Hypothetical questions are ok here, but in moderation.  The emphasis here is that we help actual people with actual issues that they encounter in their own workplaces.

To date, you appear to have created numerous (almost 10) different Stack Exchange profiles to ask very different questions, one per user (we have no idea why you've done this).  While this isn't against the rules, it does go against the ethos of the site here.

The question here was removed because it looks as though it's contrived, and it appears to be part of a wider pattern.

You're free to continue asking questions, but we'd ask that they address actual situations that you're actually facing.

Thanks.

Comment: I have created 2 accounts to post this question because I've never received confirmation email for the first one. In both case I use temporary mail created on the fly online. For sure I've not created 10 (or more) accounts as you are suggesting. I don't see why I should have done this.

Comment: @LukeD Use the Contact Us link to ask SE to merge all your accounts, if that is indeed the case.

Comment: *"I don't see why I should have done this."* We don't see why you should do this either, the reason is best known to you.